# Helpful flags with option "very low quality". Is this considered "hacking"?

Tags: support, flags

I'm checking *Low Quality Posts* queues and I see this post:

[image: 1]

Maybe there was someone flagged the answer with option *very low quality*.

When I see it, I've tried to right-click on the title of the question to check the answer again in the new tab. And I confirm that the answer really has *very low quality*.

Then, I've tried to flag the answer with same option:

[image: 2]

Server accepts. Then I would have 1 *helpful flag* easily. Someone flagged it to me, I receive and flag again before sending it to moderators.

With 3k reputation, I can review maximum 20 posts per day. Imagine that I flag 10 posts like that per day, I can easy to get *Deputy* badge in 8 days (*Raise 80 helpful flags*).

My question: Is this considered hacking?

Comment: You should be able to find many comments (and some other things) to flag by just using the site regularly. You could also identify some patterns in undesirable comments and write a script in [data.se] to identify them for easy flagging (although you should only do this (a) on popular on-topic posts and (b) if you also flag other comments on those posts that should be removed, otherwise you're probably wasting the time of the mods more than you're helping).

Comment: Whenever you look at the badges you earned, you'll be reminded how you got it.  For ever and ever and nothing you can do about it.

Comment: If you focus on the badge so much, you will miss on the very important point, which is "badges exist to encourage certain behaviors on the site". If you do what's needed to get the badge without understanding the intent of the badge or how it benefit the site... you're missing on a lot of opportunities for learning

Comment: [Live footage of SO stoping the infamous Hacker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msX4oAXpvUE).SO headquarter is defending against your powerfull hack. Hopefully you had no power glove

Comment: Imo if you do your review correctly, no one cares about who raised the flag.

Comment: @DragandDrop Are they... are they typing on the same keyboard at the same time!? That's it. I quit.

Comment: That post is not VLQ.

Comment: @Gimby, It's Hollywood "Piano four hands". 2 people 1 keyboard, typing in 10+ Interface at the same time. This scene lack of a 3rd doing some mouse programming. It's a proof that adding new people to a project will speed up the process even if you have no more ressource or computer avaidable.

Comment: @DragandDrop I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're talking about. I'm not posting this question here to get insult. If you still comment like that (which not related to this post), I will flag your comment as spam. Regard.

Comment: Hi @TânNguyễn , There is no evil in my comment, no insult, no pedentric statement.
It's just a visual joke about the miss conception of what quoted-hacking is.
This miss conception happend every time It has so screen time in a movie or serie. 
If it didn't made you smile, I'm sorry for it. Blame my poor english, and my lack of communication skill. My second comment, is underlining the fact that while IT will see this scene as a joke. Most of the manager will think that you can have two people on the same keyboard.

Comment: The power glove is an old Nes controller, picture it as the infinity gauntlet of caricatural hackers. Im not making a caricature of you, I'm answering the question. It's not an hack.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not hacking. Similarly, voting on random posts to get your electorate badge is not hacking.

It's wasting your time and flags to get a badge, though. And it's not helpful for the site.

If you want to get the deputy badge fast, going to a moderation-oriented chat room, for example, the [New Answers to Old Questions Headquarters](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126814/new-answers-to-old-questions-headquarters), probably is even faster. And it's actually helpful to the site, while flagging already flagged posts isn't.